# How to limit a string to a set of dynamically-defined values?

Tags: c#

I have a class that has a `string` property for which I'd like to limit the possible values to a set defined dynamically (e.g. stored in the database, though we're using code-first EF6).  Using an `Enum` is obviously out.  I did some reading about **Code Contracts** and like the look of that, but don't know the first thing about establishing a `Contract.Requires` that pulls back a set of values.  Lambda, maybe?  I'm on the bleeding edge of my understanding here.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class Rule
{
    /// <summary>The Conditions associated with this Rule
    /// </summary>
    public ICollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }

    // ... some other stuff ...

    /// <summary>The Status of the Rule.
    /// </summary>
    public string RuleStatus 
    { 
    get{}
    set
    {
        // Here's where I want to dynamically determine values
        Contract.Requires(value == "Inactive"||"Obsolete");
        // Perhaps something like this, 
        // where GetValidRuleStatuses returns an array of string??
        Contract.Requires(GetValidRuleStatuses().Contains(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the values going to change after compilation? If that is not the case you could use the t4 engine to create an enum.

Comment: Create a custom type for the field that does the checking for you?

Comment: The values may change after compilation.  In the above example code, I imagine `GetValidRuleStatuses()` to run a Linq query, returning an array of current entries in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this, is to write custom code to actually perform the check as and when you need to.

In terms of data structures, I'd recommend a `HashSet<string>` for fast lookups, which you will need to populate:

```
//Cache this somewhere, until the values change
var allowedValues = new HashSet<string>(stringValues);

if(!allowedValues.Contains(attemptedValue))
{
    //Throw exception?
}
```

Comment: No need for a hash set; the number of values will be small, around 8-10 strings.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach. I'd have to put in some sort of event to refresh the cache when a value changes, but that's probably less expensive than my initial approach of getting valid statuses every time the user creates a new object.  Now just to wrench it into a Contract...

Comment: I tried using a Contract, but couldn't figure them out.  In the end I fell back to something based on your suggestion.